# How to get "resize" type of cursor when hovering on the border of the box?

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to change a cursor property from `:default` to `:se-resize` when hover on the **border** of a box **only**. Is there any way how I can do it in in CSS? I need options **only** in CSS please!

The HTML:

```
<textarea placeholder="..."></textarea>
```

The CSS:

```
textarea {
width: 510px;
height: 140px;
padding: 5px 0;
border:2px solid #dddddd;
outline-style:none;
color: #777777;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this with a wrapping DIV that has the CSS for the hover.

```css
.border {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: e-resize;
  padding: 5px;
}

.contents {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: default;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<div class="contents">
  Hello World
</div>
</div>
```

Also here: https://jsfiddle.net/vyk4c21b/9/

Comment: thanks, there is only 1 problem, on horizontal border, cursor is vertical!

Comment: Thank you ! You've made my day!